# $\nabla f$ Lipschitz & $f$ Lipschitz (Lipshitz of function's gradient and lipshitz function )

Tags: convex-optimization, lipschitz-functions, subgradient

My question is:

> Which of the following is more restrictive? $\nabla f$ Lipschitz & $f$ Lipschitz

I think each one cannot imply the other.

For example ($1$D): $$f(x) = \frac {x^2}{3}$$

In this case, $f(x)$ is **not** Lipschitz; however, $\nabla f = \frac{2}{3}x $ is Lipschitz.

For example ($1$D):

$$f(x) = |x|$$
In this case, $f(x)$ is Lipschitz; however, $\nabla f$ is not.

Is this correct?

Here, I just give two example. Can I say this just by two examples or is there any deeper discussion in this question?

Comment: In your second example $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. Try to find a differentiable EVERYWHERE function that is not Lipschitz.

Comment: If it does exist, then $f$ Lipschitz seems more restrictive (in the case of differentiable everywhere)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally, the continuity of $\nabla f$ implies that $f$ is Lipschitz. For example, the Mean Value Theorem implies that in on a convex set,
$$
f(x)-f(y)=(x-y)\cdot\nabla f(\xi)\tag{1}
$$
for some $\xi$ on the line between $x$ and $y$. Thus,
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\le|x-y|\sup_\xi|\nabla f(\xi)|\tag{2}
$$

So in a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\nabla f$ being Lipschitz implies that $\nabla f$ is bounded and $(2)$ implies that $f$ is Lipschitz. Therefore, $\nabla f$ being Lipschitz is more restrictive.

However, as your first example shows on an unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, even a $C^\infty$ function need not be Lipschitz.